# SSH programming with Python 3 paramiko, EOFError when trying to execute commands

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Wizards of stackoverflow. I'm trying to read in commands from a .txt file to SSH using paramiko. Currently it will read in the first line from the file and execute it. When I get to the second line though, it will throw an EOFError and quit. I put a check in to see if the second command makes it to print and it does, however, it does not execute. I was hoping someone would be able to help and solve this issue with me. Here is my code:

```
from paramiko import client
import logging
import os

#Clear the screen before starting the script
os.system('cls')

# Prompting for the user input config file
filename = input('Input configuration filename, the file extension must be attached: ')

# Creating the LOG file for the execution of the config file
logFileName = "LOG" + filename[0:]
try:
    logging.basicConfig(filename= logFileName ,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level= logging.DEBUG)
    print ("The file was created!")
except IOError:
    print ("File failed to create")

logging.info("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")
logging.info("NEW CONFIGURATION LOG ENTRY")
logging.info("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")


# Class for creating an SSH client, logging in, letting us write out commands, and close the client.
class ssh:
    client = None
    def __init__(self, address, username, password):


        print ("Connecting to server...")
        logging.info('Connecting to server...')

        self.client = client.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(address, username= username, password= password, look_for_keys= False)

        logging.info("Address: " + address)
        logging.info("Username: " + username)
        print ("Connection successful!")
        logging.info('Connection successful!')

    def sendCommand(self, command):
        if (self.client):
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
            receiveData = b""
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
                receiveData += stdout.channel.recv(1024)

            if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                received = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                while received:
                    receiveData += received
                    received = stdout.channel.recv(1024)

            if receiveData:
                print (str(receiveData, "utf8"))

            else:
                print ("stdout is empty")
        else:
            print ("Connection failed, check credentials and try again..")
            logging.warning('Connection failed, check credentials and try again..')

connection = ssh('0.0.0.0', 'test', 'test')
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        connection.sendCommand(line)
```

**The .txt file would read something like this:**

configure terminal

Interface Gi0/9

description Test_Interface

*Any help is much appreciated, thank you.*

Comment: Current implementation of `sendCommand` some times not receive server output. Is it same as in original code, or simplified version?

Comment: @Arnial its the same as the original version

Answer (score 1):

Possible bug. Current implementation of `sendCommand` may not receive output (or full output).

Reason
`exit_status_ready` is a non blocking way to find that exit status is received. It is possible that lastpart of output still not readed by script. You need to call `recv` after `while` if `recv_ready` is `True`.

Also, I don't think that checking `recv_ready` in while loop is good idea. It's non-blocking method. Because of it `while` loop will uselessly run multiple times, just wasting your CPU power.

This version work for me:

```
receiveData = b""
while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    receiveData += stdout.channel.recv( 2048 )

if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
    received = stdout.channel.recv( 2048 )
    while received: #received will be empty only when all data received
        receiveData += received
        received = stdout.channel.recv( 2048 )

if receiveData:
    print( str( receiveData, "utf8" ) )
else:
    print( "stdout is empty" )
```

Also I should mention that there is easer way to build string from output. You can use the fact that `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are file like objects.

Here simpler example for `stderr` (it may be good idea to read it too):

```
data = ""
for line in stderr:
    #line in string already (probably will work only if locale is utf8)
    data += line 

if data:
    print( data ) 
else:
    print( "stderr is empty" )
```

Update: 
if you don't have multiple commands on one line then

```
filename = input('Input configuration filename, the file extension must be attached: ')
# define ssh class here (i'll skip it to make it shorter)

connection = ssh('0.0.0.0', 'test', 'test')
with open(filename) as f:
   for line in f:
       connection.sendCommand( line )
```

If you have several commands per line just split them to array of different commands.

Comment: The code will read the file, however if I have 2 or more commands it only reads the last one. It could have something to do with my reading in the file, however, I'm unsure of a way to fix this.

Comment: It threw me an error when trying to execute the commands, more detailed in new code I posted. Thanks.